# After compiling code with babel, property doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a file located at models/user.js with the following content:

```
import { mongoose } from '../index.js'

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String, // Self-explanatory
    password: String, // This will be a bcrypt hash
    name: String,
    verified: Boolean
})

export var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

Babel compiles it into ES5 which yields:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.User = undefined;

var _index = require('../index.js');

var userSchema = _index.mongoose.Schema({
    email: String, // Self-explanatory
    password: String, // This will be a bcrypt hash
    name: String,
    verified: Boolean
});

var User = exports.User = _index.mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

In `index.js`, I have this requirement for `mongoose`

```
export const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

and Babel converts that over to

```
var mongoose = exports.mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

This all looks good to me, but whenever I run my (compiled through Babel) code, I get an error telling me that _index.mongoose.Schema can't be found, which doesn't make sense because everything looks like it's related properly. `index.js` is in the correct place relative to user.js

The really weird thing is that I have a sort of "project template" that I use when creating the type of project that I am, and everything compiles (with this essentially the same code) completely fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You really should not do that. Just `import mongoose from 'mongoose'` in the places where you actually need it instead of relying on re-exported values. The compilation process will look after the same import being in several places. Also NodeJS itself only ever evaluates a "required" module only once, no matter how many times such statements appear.

Comment: @NeilLunn This ended up working, thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve the initial issue, but @NeilLunn provided a great workaround. Instead of trying to import the module from my `index.js`, because Node only evals a module once, you can just import it (same as how you did in index.js) in your secondary file.